# After upgrading my Cordapps to v4.1, my Junits are working fine but getting error mentioned on server, How to resolve this?

Tags: java, corda

Error which I'm getting is mentioned below.

It was working fine until finality flow change, and I'm passing the same session set into finalityFlow. I am aware that the participants need to be added and not only the signers, they are same in this case. Really confused in what might be causing this problem. And If Junits are successfully why it fails when cordapp is run on server?

````
net.corda.core.flows.UnexpectedFlowEndException: Tried to access ended session SessionId(toLong=4575033585699842324) with empty buffer
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.fillInLocalStackTrace(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:174) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.processEventsUntilFlowIsResumed(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:162) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.suspend(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:446) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowSessionImpl.receive(FlowSessionImpl.kt:67) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowSessionImpl.receive(FlowSessionImpl.kt:71) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.ReceiveTransactionFlow.call(ReceiveTransactionFlow.kt:100) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.ReceiveTransactionFlow.call(ReceiveTransactionFlow.kt:28) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.subFlow(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:329) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:314) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.ReceiveFinalityFlow.call(FinalityFlow.kt:256) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.ReceiveFinalityFlow.call(FinalityFlow.kt:251) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.subFlow(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:329) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:314) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
    at com.chainthat.insurance.placement.flow.bermuda.carrier.UploadFirmOrderRiskContractResponderFlow.call(UploadFirmOrderRiskContractResponderFlow.java:53) ~[?:?]
    at com.chainthat.insurance.placement.flow.bermuda.carrier.UploadFirmOrderRiskContractResponderFlow.call(UploadFirmOrderRiskContractResponderFlow.java:15) ~[?:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:269) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:45) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:63) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]```
````

Answer (score 0):

this is caused by misaligned send and receives, usually because there is a condition like if (states > 0) etc.

In order to resolve the issue for you, you will need to share the flow code (both initiating and responding).

You can DM the code to one of our engineers on Slack.